# Solving for $t$ in $t=x^t$

Tags: logarithms

Is it possible to solve for $t$ in $t=x^t$? 
Using log on both sides does not seem to help.
$$\log t=t\log x$$
$$\log x=\frac{\log t}t$$

Comment: in base 10. If it is natural, what would be the difference?

Comment: If you are asking whether you can write $t=f(x)$ where the function $f$ is composed of "elementary" functions, the answer is no. And it does not matter what the base of the logarithm is.

Comment: $(t,x)=(1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$.......integer solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done using [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
The solution for this particular equation is

$$t = \frac{W\left(-\log x\right)}{-\log x} = e^{-W(-\log x)}=h(x),$$

where $h$ is Euler's iterated exponential.